# Matlab - property set to [] after access

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a simple data loading class:

```
classdef DataLoader
    properties
        data;
    end

    methods
        function obj = loadData(obj, file)
            obj.data = csvread(file);
        end
    end
end
```

After the data is loaded, I can see that the object reports the data is in:

```
s = DataLoader();
s.loadData('data.csv')
ans = 

  DataLoader with properties:

    data: [8738102×8 double]
```

However, when I access the data:

```
s.data

ans =

     []
```

Furthermore, after this access:

```
s = 

  DataLoader with properties:

    data: []
```

EDIT: so I've solved my problem:

```
s = s.loadData('data.csv');
```

but is there a way to do just:

```
s.loadData('data.csv');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered already, you have to overwrite your old object with the new object returned by `loadData`, since your class is a [value class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html). If you want your object to have reference-like behavior, it needs to inherit from the [handle class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle-class.html). This is what your new class code will look like:

```
classdef DataLoader < handle  % Inherit from handle class
    properties
        data;
    end

    methods
        function loadData(obj, file)  % No need to return output now
            obj.data = csvread(file);
        end
    end
end
```

Now you can use the following syntax:

```
s.loadData('data.csv');
```

Comment: I would add since this question is also marked as 'octave', that octave prefers the "older" object oriented style, and uses different optimisations under the hood (specifically [this](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Indexed-Assignment-Optimization.html#Indexed-Assignment-Optimization)), and only has limited support for `classdef` classes for now. (see: https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.2/classdef-Classes.html )